# How to create overlay network for docker, getting error datastore for scope "global" is not initialized

Tags: docker, overlays

I am trying to create a network using docker 1.71 ubuntu image.

Everything is installed and working fine, however when I try to create my own network, I get the following error:

```
$docker network create -d overlay test
Error response from daemon: datastore for scope "global" is not initialized
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [issue 939](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/939#issuecomment-225574179)

> the error clearly indicates that the daemon is not running in the newly introduced agent mode ([docker/libnetwork#1149](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/pull/1149)). Without that, daemon will expect KV-Store to be configured for any overlay network to be created.

For docker as ancient as 1.7, I would first upgrade it.
If not, try at least "[Set up a key-value store¶](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/#/step-1-set-up-a-key-value-store)"